# onblur replacement in case of multiple input elements

Tags: javascript, events, onblur

I've got a webpage with some text structure. I want the structure to be a editable in an "in place" manner.

In some cases it's fairly easy (at least so far). I make `onclick` event that sets `display: none` on the text and create an input. Then I set some events to save the new content using AJAX. The problematic thing is canceling of edition. Here I would make it using `onblur` event that fire removing `<input>` fields and making the text visible again.

HTML example 1:

```
<div class="text_bar">
    <div class="text" onclick="edit(this.parentNode)"></div>
</div>
```

JS fragment:

```
function edit(parentElement){

    function cancelEditing(){
        textInput.onblur = null // for Chrome
        textInput.parentNode.removeChild(textInput)
        text.style.display = 'inline-block'
    }

    var text = parentElement.getElementsByClassName('text')[0]

    var textInput = document.createElement('input')
    textInput.setAttribute('type','text')
    textInput.value = text.textContent
    textInput.onkeydown = function(event){
        /* not that important */
    }
    textInput.onblur = cancelEditing

    text.style.display = 'none';
    parentElement.insertBefore(textInput, text.nextElementSibling)
    textInput.focus()

}
```

There are however some cases, when two texts are closely related. So I'd like to show two `<input>` elements, the problem is with canceling. I'd like the user to be able to switch freely between inputs (with mouse or keyboard) but the fields need to close in case the user clicks somewhere else.

HTML example 2:

```
<div class="text_bar">
    <div class="prefix" onclick="edit(this.parentNode)"></div>
    <div class="text" onclick="edit(this.parentNode)"></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately onblur `fires` before `onclick`, otherwise I could for example stop transmitting events if the other input was clicked and problem would be solved. But it's not the case. How can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe it's a bit off-topic, but did you know of "contenteditable" html attribute? It makes the dom completely editable and is supported since IE 5.5

Comment: Thanks, certainly worth testing. Generally I'm still wary about HTML5 features. Is there no problem controlling this with CSS?

Comment: Actually, for contenteditable attribute the history is quite unique: it was first implemented by Microsoft on IE 5.5, and then reverse engineered on all other browsers. It's not HTML5, it's pure old classic HTML. And yes, you can control it 100%. It was meant to transform the browser in a pure DOM editor.